# A projectivity $\tau: \mathbb{CP^1} \to \mathbb{CP^1}$ such that $\tau(P_i)=Q_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am struggling hours with this problem, which probably has a fast solution, but it hasn't come up in my mind yet:

Let $P_i$ and $Q_i$, $i \in \{1,2,3\}$, be two projective frames of $\mathbb{CP^1}$, determine a projectivity $\tau: \mathbb{CP^1} \to \mathbb{CP^1}$ such that $\tau(P_i)=Q_i$.

$P_1:
    \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, $P_2:
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ $P_3:
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

$Q_1:
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    -i \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$ $Q_2:
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, $Q_2:
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    i \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$

Basically, I must solve this system:

$\tau=
    \begin{bmatrix}
    a&b \\
    c&d \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$, so that: $\begin{cases}
b=k \\
d=-ik
\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}
a=s \\
c=s\end{cases}$, $\begin{cases}
 a+b =t\\
c+d=it\end{cases}$

Any suggestion? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $z:=[z, 1]$, $\infty := [1, 0]$.

**Hint:** Do an Euclidean division first to write the projectivity in the form $a+bz$ or $a + \frac b{(c-1)z+1}$. This simplifies the system, you'll be able to find the parameters one by one.

We're not interested in the first one because it fixes $\infty$. The second sends sends $0\mapsto a+b$, sends
$\infty \mapsto a$ and $1 \mapsto a+b/c$.

> Thus we can solve for $a, b, c$ in that order! We have $a = \tau(\infty) = 1$. Next, $b = \tau(0) - a = i - 1$. Finally $c = b/(\tau(1)-a) = \frac{i-1}{-i-1} = -i$. We find
> $$\tau(z) = 1+ \frac{i-1}{(-i-1)z+1} = \frac{(-i-1)z+i}{(-i-1)z+1}$$
> That is, $$\tau = \begin{bmatrix}-i-1&i \\-i-1&1 \\\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: This is just brilliant, thank you!

Comment: A second question: if I had a point: $[1, \lambda]$, where $\lambda$ is a general real or complex number, to find $\tau([1, \lambda])$ should I just apply the matrix?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And keep in mind that $[a,b] = [1, b/a]$.

Comment: I have a question too, are you used to view $\lambda  \in \mathbb C$ as $[1, \lambda]$ or as $[\lambda, 1]$?

Comment: We use the notation $[1, \lambda]$

Comment: Ok! In my answer I used $[\lambda, 1]$ so I hope that isn't confusing...

Comment: It isn't: you've been extremely clear, thank you!

Comment: This is interesting, how have to found the values of the matrix?

Comment: @Arcticmonkey See edit; we can 'read' them when we write $\tau(z)$ as a fraction.

Comment: @barto I am sorry, I haven't been clear: why $\tau (0)-a=i-1$? For example. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Arcticmonkey $\tau(0) := \tau([0,1]) = [1,-i] = [i,1] =: i$ and similarly for the others

Comment: @barto got it! When the notation is $[1, z]$ then $\tau ([0,1])=[1,-i]=:-i$? Because same here we're using Niegel Hitchin's handout with the  $\infty :=[0,1]$

Comment: @Arcticmonkey I used the convention $\lambda = [\lambda, 1]$ throughout my answer, as I said in an earlier comment. If you use the other convention, just swap $0$ and $\infty$; the answer and the computation stay the same.

Comment: @barto how to swap $0$ and $\infty$? Because using a projectivity so defined the matrix I found is $
    \begin{bmatrix}
    1+i & 4+2i \\
    i-2 &2 \\    \end{bmatrix}
$, which works anyway